# Generate similar phrases based on user's input

Tags: python, word2vec

I'd like to generate LSI (latent semantic indexing) keywords based on user's input
I have used wordnet to generate similar words (synonyms), but I don't know how to apply that for phrases

Example of what I'm trying to do :

```
input = "cheap car"
Output = "cheap cars for sale near me" , "used cars "
```

Python Code for word synonyms

```
initial_kw = "buy"
synonyms = []

for syn in wordnet.synsets(initial_kw):
    for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(l.name())


generated_kw = list(set(synonyms))
```

The results are relatively bad though !!

I have read that I can use something like "word2vec" then K nearest neighbor for better results, but still don't know how I can apply this for phrases. I don't even know if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure how often the *wordnet* database is updated, because it seems to be missing words.  I'm the author of the Python package
[wordhoard](https://pypi.org/project/wordhoard/), which can produce a list of synonyms. `Wordhoard` can also be used to find semantic relationships between words including a word's synonyms, synonyms, hypernyms, hyponyms and homophones.

```
from wordhoard import Synonyms

synonym_list = Synonyms('buy').find_synonyms()
print(len(synonym_list))
# output
73

print(synonym_list)
# output 
['accretion', 'acquire', 'acquiring', 'acquisition', 'addition',
'asset', 'attainment', 'bad buy', 'bad deal', 'bargain', 'booty', 
'bribe', 'budget price', 'buy back', 'buy food', 'buy out', 'buy up',
'choose', 'closeout', 'compromise', 'conception','contract', 'covenant', 
'deal', 'discount', 'gain', 'gaining', 'get', 'getting hold of', 'giveaway', 
'good buy', 'good deal', 'good value', 'holding', 'impulse-buy', 'investment', 
'low price', 'markdown', 'nominal price', 'obtain', 'order', 'pay', 'pay for', 
'pennyworth', 'pick out', 'pick up', 'pledge', 'possession', 'prearrangement', 
'prize', 'procure', 'procuring', 'property', 'purchase', 'reduction', 
'repurchase', 'sale', 'score', 'secure', 'select', 'shop', 'snip', 
'something purchased', 'steal', 'subscribe', 'subscribe to', 'take', 
'take out', 'take over', 'trade', 'transaction', 'understanding', 'value']
```